# react RouteHandler is not rendering DefaultRoute

Tags: javascript, react-router, rendering

I have following code. I am getting  component. But, the  is not rendering the default route specified in routes.js. I am not getting any error upon running the code. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Here is code of index.js file:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./routes');
var RouterStore = require('./stores/RouterStore');

var router = Router.create({routes: routes, location: Router.HistoryLocation, scrollBehavior: Router.ScrollToTopBehavior});

RouterStore.set(router);
router.run(function(Root){
 ReactDOM.render(
  <Root flux={flux}/>,
  document.getElementById('myApp')
 );
});
```

Here is code of myapp.js file:

```
var React = require('react');
var Fluxxor = require('fluxxor');
var RouteHandler = require('react-router').RouteHandler;
var Nav = require('./nav');

var myApp = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Nav />
       <RouteHandler />
     </div>
   );
 }
})

module.exports = myApp;
```

Here is code of routes.js file:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;

var myApp = require('./components/myapp');
var Progress = require('./components/progress');

function LoadingWrapper(component) {

 return React.createClass({
   mixins:[component.Mixin],
   renderUnavailable : function(){
     return (<Progress />);
   }
 });
}

var routes = (
 <Route handler={myApp}>
   <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={LoadingWrapper(require('react-proxy?name=featured!./components/featured/home'))} />
 </Route>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

Comment: Hi, can anyone guide me for this? I have gone through several documents, but I am still stuck.